# Cannot open word document and Excel from Sharepoint 2010

Tags: document, excel, word

I am not able to open any word documents and Excel from my Sharepoint2010 sites. I was able to open them before I re-installed everything from scratch.

When I try and open any uploaded Excel document it says: 
  *"The workbook cannot be opened" (with in the browser)*

When I try and open a word document it says: 
 
 *"Word experienced an error trying to open the file.
   Try these suggestions. 
 
   *Check the file permissions for the document or drive. 
 
   *Make sure there is sufficient free memory and disk space. 
 
   *Open the file with the Text Recovery converter. 
 
    (http:// name of my SP site URL/NameofDocument.docx)*

I am not sure how to react to these suggestions. I am sure there is enough disk space and I am logged in as admin so I have the full right.

**

*I am using a 32bit Office in with Sharepoint 2010. Do you think that might be the problem?*

**

Answer (score 1):

The server version (x64) and the client office version (x86) are not related and will not eb your problem. What browser are you using? If it is IE check to see if you accedently started the x64 version. This version is not able to run the needed active x controls.

Answer (score 0):

Try to repair your office installation. We have noticed similar problems in our organisation where users were reporting the same thing after office patches.

Bellow is a link to how to repair office 2010 http://www.opengatesw.net/ms-access-tutorials/Repairing-Office-Install.htm

Comment: I will try that once I get to back to my system. Any specific thing that I need to notice while repairing?

Comment: I did the repair that did not help, then I actually uninstalled MS Office and installed it but all in vein.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Site Settings - Site Collection Features and check the settings for how Clients open documents (in the Browser or in the Client application).

It would also be important to know if this is ALL documents or specific libriaries (the Client settings can be applied under the Library Settings as well (advanced)).

Also, do you have Office Web Applications installed? If so, try installing again (or opt for the Repair option).

If nothing above works, check to ensure that Office applications are installed on the server - I've seen many cases where that fixes a number of issues (including Data Views).

David Sterling
CEO/Sterling International Consulting Group

Comment: I tried that in two different libraries for excel (one was just a random custom library and I was about to use the other one for my Trusted Excel sites) and for the word document I used the random library I made and then the shared library as well. In all the cases I was promoted with those errors.I checked and make sure all the related features are activated but that not helping as well. Is there some specific feature that I need to check? I uninstalled MS Office and re installed it but all in vein same error.